# What is the function of the getContentPane() in javax.swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've visit a lot of tutorials about Java Swing, and i was wondering was the difference between adding a component using `<ObjectJFame>.getContentPane().add();` 
or using `<ObjectJFrame>.add()`,
and which is the best? (if there is a "better").

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Comment: Many of the methods associated with a frame have being redirected to the content pane (they act as a proxy).  The problem is, not all the method have (I'm looking at you `removeAll`).  While you can use either, generally speaking, it's typically recommended to use `getContentPane().xxx` as it ensures you are actually calling the method you think you are calling...

Answer (score 2):

There is effectively no difference between `getContentPane().add()` and `myJFrame.add()`. I think it was back in the big Java 2 (JDK 1.5) revamp that adding directly to a top level UI component just forwarded to the underlying content pane.

Personally, I use `getContentPane()` for the sake of clarity, but whatever you do, be consistent about it so that you (including the future you) and other people) will know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I used the Swing library, I always add component using the second method. Actually, both functions do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

> ...
>   As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been
>   overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary. This means you
>   can write:
>
> ```
>    frame.add(child);
> ```
>
> ...

So there should be no difference.